# can't install cocoapods MacBook Air m1

Tags: cocoapods, apple-m1

can't run sudo gem install ffi I get this error

ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue by updating ruby version to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with these lines of codes;

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

It worked for me; I hope you can solve your problem using this.